# 2 outlets not working, breaker is not bad

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker, voltage

We have 2 outlets (one on each side of the wall) that stopped working suddenly. All other outlets and switches on the same breaker (before and after these 2 in the chain) are working fine. We have replaced the outlets and tested the breakers. Still nothing to these 2 outlets. When we tested the voltage, it was reading with power still. Does anyone know what could be causing this? My husband has worked in the electrical industry for many years and has never seen anything like this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you examined the _other_ outlets? Those upstream may have faulty connections that don't impact the outlet at their particular boxes.

Comment: Yes, all other outlets (on the same breaker and other breakers) are working just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting my point. There may be pigtail or other connections (backstabs) at those locations that have failed. Check _all_ connections on the circuit.

Comment: How sure are you of: **before and after these 2 in the chain**? Turn off power. Disconnect the problem receptacles. Cap the wires. Turn on power. See if anything else is **not** working. If everything else is working, next step: take a picture of the wires in each problem receptacle box and upload so we can see.

Comment: Ask your husband "I understand how power gets TO the appliance, on that little black wire... but what happens then? I know it doesn't just pour out onto the floor at that point... how does power get BACK to wherever it comes from?"  About 5 minutes into 'splaining that, your husband will figure out the problem :)  (fyi it goes back on the white wire *if it can*)

Comment: How are you checking for power? You said it was reading power a tic tester, volt meter? A single line in a chain to these 2 receptacles could be where the fault on a neutral at that location.